# ErrorException in helpers.php line 533:

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm making a contact form with laravel 5.4 and I want to get an email when someone sends the contact form. I'm using Mailtrap to receive emails.

The problem I'm getting is that I get this error when I submit the form.

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 533:
>   htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\app\Modules\Templates\Resources\Views\emails\contact.blade.php)

My contact function

```
public function contact()
{
    $data = Input::all();

    $rules = array(
        'name' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'message' => '',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

    if($validator->passes())
    {
        Mail::send('templates::emails.contact', $data, function($message){
            $message->from(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'));
            $message->to('info@site.com', 'Info')->subject('Testing contact form');
        });

        Session::flash('success', 'Your message has been sent successfully.');
        return back();
    }else{
        return back()->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

and my contact.blade.php that is the information that gets sent to me

```
<h1>We been contacted by.... </h1>

{{ $name }}<br />
{{ $email }}<br />
{{ $subject }}<br />
{{ $message }}<br />
```

Comment: Can you debug the `$data`? Add `dd($data);` before the validation in the contact function.

Comment: you need to save the variables that you are passing to the view, else direct by Input the blade wont get it

Comment: @Jerodev - When I debug `$data` I get the information that I entered in my form which is `array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "mI35WN4IGUlefCi4XXT80nhKcM2Cc3esosFtUTKX"
  "name" => "test name"
  "email" => "email@gmail.com"
  "subject" => "test"
  "message" => "drgrg"
]`

Comment: @Exprator - Isn't that what the `$data` does in the line `Mail::send(('templates::emails.contact', $data, function($message)` It grabs the data and passes it to the contact.blade.php

Comment: @Shiva478 then you need to pass $data['name'] instead of $name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the `$data` which holds the array of input. You need to access them like shown below.

Change the data being passed to

```
Mail::send('templates::emails.contact', compact('data'), function($message)
```

Change your view code to

```
{{ $data['name'] }}<br/>
{{ $data['email'] }}<br/>
{{ $data['message'] }}<br/>
```

You're also trying to access subject in the view when isn't available in the input.

Comment: @Shiva478 updated my answer. Change `$data` to `compact('data')` when calling send.

Answer (score 0):

you need to Add $subject in ur cantact function or remove it from cantact.blade.php, try this code :

```js
public function contact()
{
    $cdata = Input::all();

    $crules = array(
        'name' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'subject' => '',
        'message' => '',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($cdata, $crules);

    if($validator->passes())
    {
        Mail::send('templates::emails.contact', $cdata, function($message){
            $message->from(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'));
            $message->to('info@site.com', 'Info')->subject('Testing contact form');
        });

        Session::flash('success', 'Your message has been sent successfully.');
        return back();
    }else{
        return back()->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

and some times u got an error because ur variables have the same name of stored variables ( like data,timer,for ... etc)